# How to install Cohttp with lwt support?

Tags: ocaml, opam

Running `opam install cohttp` does not provide me with `cohttp.lwt` in findlib. Am I missing a command line option to install with lwt support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lwt` is an optional dependency of `cohttp`. So to activate lwt support, you'll simply need to install it:

```
opam install ssl lwt cohttp
```

Remark: you can install lwt later on and OPAM will recompile cohttp with the right options.

Comment: But I did have lwt installed and even reinstalling the packages with `opam reinstall lwt cohttp` doesn't do anything. And checking the `lib` directory in `.opam` shows me that the cohtp_lwt modules are nowehere to be found.

Comment: Ha damn, there is no configure option, this is handled directly by cohttp ... so you can do `opam install cohttp -b` and cd ~/.opam/<switch>/build/lwt` and try to play with the Makefiles ...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `lwt` package, you need to install the `ssl` package:

```
opam install ssl lwt cohttp
```